# Is there an STL/boost algorithm to check all elements in a container match a value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

Is there an STL/boost algorithm that will test if all the elements between two iterators match a given value? Or alternatively that a predicate returns `true` for all of them?

i.e. something like

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator all_match (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value)
{
    bool allMatch = true;
    while(allMatch && first!=last)
        allMatch = (value == *first++);
    return allMatch;
}
```

Or

```
template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
bool all_true (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred)
{
    bool allTrue = true;
    while (allTrue && first != last) 
        allTrue = pred(*first++);
    return allTrue;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can negate the predicate you can use std::find / std::find_if and see if it returns the end element of your sequence. If not then it returns the one that does match.

You can adapt an function with std::not1 or std::not_equal_to so by doing combined with std::find_if you can indeed do so using STL without writing a loop.

```
bool allMatch = seq.end() == std::find_if( seq.begin(), seq.end(), 
    std::not_equal_to(val) );
bool allPass = seq.end() == std::find_if( seq.begin(), seq.end(), 
    std::not1(pred) );
```

Comment: actually I don't think that `not_equal_to()` syntax is quite right. I may be doing something wrong, but I had to use `bind2nd` with it like this: `std::find_if(seq.begin(), seq.end(), std::bind2nd(std::not_equal_to<MyType>(), val))`

Answer (score 21):

C++11 introduces `std::all_of`.

Comment: @avakar: Section 25.1 [algorithms.general] It also introduces `std::any_of` and `std::none_of` (and the infamous `std::copy_if`).

Comment: @avakar: we're not using C++0x but that is useful to know anyway, thanks.

Comment: This is interesting. It shows C++0x poses a shift towards a more humane interface.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I don't know if it is a shift much more than an identified need. I wasn't in the field in 2003 so I could not say if the C++03 standard was the occasion for such an adjustment too.

Comment: @GrahamS: you're not alone, it isn't even standard yet and the support is lacking for most compilers, so most of us "professional" are stuck with C++03 at work. It doesn't prevent us to use those features to experiment at home though :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use std:find ord std::find_if to do this.

```
template <class T>
struct pred {
    T t_;

    pred(const T& value) : t_(value) {}

    bool operator()(const T &t)
    {
        return t != t_;
    }
};

if (e.cend() == std::find_if(c.cbegin(), c.cend(), pred<T>(value)))
    print("all match value");
```

Comment: As I understand it, find and find_if only locate the first match in a container. I want to check that EVERY element between the iterators is a given value.

Comment: Aah I see. So define a predicate that is true if it the element doesn't match, then see if find_if reaches the end or not. Cunning, thanks. +1

Comment: There is already a predicate to test not equal, std::not_equal_to, and no need to write your own.

Comment: @CashCow you are right. This was youst to illustrate how it works and maybe equality in the sense of operator == is not the predicate the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::equal` with the predicate. Something like:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::lambda;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    bool allMatch = equal(a.begin(), a.begin() + 2, a.begin(), _1 == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Often you can just count them:

```
template<class FwdIterator, class T>
InputIterator all_match (FwdIterator first, FwdIterator last, const T& value)
{
   return std::count(first, last, value) == std::distance(first, last);
}
```

Inefficient when the iterator isn't random, or when it returns false. Doesn't work for input iterators.

Comment: Also doesn't stop as soon as it finds a non-match, which makes it less ideal for very large containers.